# Forking private Github Repo that may get deleted

Tags: github, fork, private

I am taking over a project from a previous contractor and all the code is in a private Github repo. I forked it which now appears as a private repo in my account but I read that if he closes his private repo (which will happen) then my forked repo will get deleted.

So, what's the best way to get this into my own Private repo with all the history behind it? Should I just clone the fork now to my own Private repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just clone your fork using `--bare` option, and next push it to another remote using `--mirror` option:

```
$ git clone --bare https://github.com/exampleuser/old-repository.git
$ cd old-repository.git
$ git push --mirror https://github.com/exampleuser/new-repository.git
```

For more details look into [this GitHub help page](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/).

Comment: Thanks @qzb On the last command, the push, I keep getting "cannot resolve host: github" yet I don't have any proxy / firewall and I tried `git config --global --unset https.proxy`